# Additional [tag] Filter

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is it possible to add another filter for personal tags, like **"Not Favorite Tags"**?

It's just when I'm browsing for my favorites, there are those that uses framework or another plugins that I have no knowledge off, yet they are in the scope of my chosen tags. And I need to scroll some more just to find those that are within my favorite tags.

Or did I just missed it and there is already some feature like that?

Comment: Nope, it's by design, since tags are supposed to be flat. If you see questions tagged with something yet not of your interest, that makes a strong case to remove the tag.

Comment: If you edit your Favorite Tags, there is another section of Ignored Tags. You can add the framework to that. For instance, I don't care to know what "YII" is, but I follow `javascript` so I added `javascript` to my Favorite Tags and `yii` to me Ignored Tags, and now I don't see YII questions on my Interesting tab.

Comment: So there is an **Ignored Tag**, thanks for the info